# How to plot histogram in R and have exact axis values.

Tags: r, plot, distribution, axis, histogram

Basically I want to plot a histogram of data in R, but don't want to x axis scale to be (0, 20, 40, 60, 80). I want it to have the exact values as they appear in my data. So for example, if my data contained these values: (0, 0, 2, 5, 7, 12, 14), I want my x axis to have these numbers and not a general scale. The y axis will then have the frequencies as it already does. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just interested in counts of possible values, and not a true histogram, then `barplot` would be appropriate:

```
x <- c(0, 0, 2, 5, 7, 12, 14)
uval <- sort(unique(x))
counts <- rowSums(sapply(x, function(x) x==uval))
barplot(counts, names=uval)
```

[image]